# Is every topology metric inducible?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

So I'm trying to show that not every topology is metric inducible.

I take a set $X$. Now take $J = \{\emptyset, X, A, X-A\}$ where $A \subset X$.

Assume the metric space $(X,d)$ induces $J$. Now since $A$ is open in $X$, for $a \in A$ there exists some $r > 0$ such that $B(a,r) \subset A$. But the only open sets in $(X,d)$ are $\emptyset, X, A, X-A$. This implies $B(a,r) = \emptyset$ which isn't possible.

So we conclude $J$ isn't inducible by any metric.

Is this proof okay?

Comment: It is not correct. You cannot say there exist $r$ such that $B(a,r)$v is a proper subset of $A$. We may have $B(a,r)=A$.

Comment: If I understand you right, you're trying to find a topology that is not metrizable--that there is no metric yielding that topology.  You might look at the finite complement topology example.

Comment: Your space is, in fact, metrizable!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You mean *pseudo*-metrisable, by $d(x,y)=0$ if $\{x,y\} \subseteq A$ or $\{x,y\} \cap A=\emptyset$ and $d(x,y)=1$ otherwise...

Answer (score 1):

That proof cannot be correct: if $X=\{1,2\}$ and $A=\{1\}$ in fact we *do* have a metrisable space (a discrete two point space). Note that we cannot claim that $B(a,r) \subset A$ but only $B(a,r) \subseteq A$; the inclusion need *not* be proper, as you seem to think.

But if $|A| \ge 2$ or $|X-A|\ge 2$ the topological space $(X,J)$ is indeed non-metrisable as there is no open set "separating" two points in that one open set, so $(X,J)$ is not $T_0$ while all metric-induced topologies are.

Comment: $(X,J)$ is still metrizable by a pseudometric.

Comment: @Magma I know but that wasn’t the question.